# Post action is not working, need help passing infromation from view into the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, url, view

Given the following form in the Index view, which includes two hidden inputs and one input that is a slider: (The hidden imputs have their values updated by a geolocation function executed on loading the page which includes:

```
document.getElementById("startLatitude").value = lattitude; 
document.getElementById("startLongitude").value = longitude;
```

where the lattitude and longitude variables have been set by the geolocation call. Also the value of the slider is updated as it is moved.)

```html
<form name="ourform" action="Index" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none">
      <li>
        <input type="hidden" name="startLatitude" id="startLatitude" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="startLongitude" id="startLongitude" value="" />10
        <input type="range" id="timeInput" min="10" max="60" value="15" step="1" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />60
      </li>
      <li>
        <br />
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="submit" name="button" value="Let's Go!" onClick="submit" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

and also an overloaded home controller method intended to receive the POST:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string timeInput, string startLatitude, string startLongitude)
{
  ...
}
```

Currently the POST action does not append the parameters to the URL when the form is submitted.
Why not?  What can be done to make sure they do? (What should be in the form attribute ACTION?)
Alternatively, is there a better method to ensure the information is passed into the controller?

Comment: What response do you get?

Comment: When you say, "the POST action does not append the parameters to the URL", I take that to mean you are looking for something like: "yourdomain.com?longitude=xxx&latitude=yyy".  However, these are form elements.  That means they are passed as parameters to your controller via the form, not the url.  Does that make sense or do I misunderstand your request?

Comment: What is the `onClick="submit"` doing for you?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know

Comment: @matthewmorris, Then you should remove it. Are you actually hitting you controller method? And you should really be generating the form element with `@using(Html.BeginForm()) { your html }` so it generates the correct `action` attribute

Comment: we are not hitting the controller method and thats the problem.

Comment: Assuming you GET method that generates this view is `Index()`, then use the code in my last comment to generate the `<form>` tag

Answer (score 0):

fix this line to be :

```
<form name="ourform" action="@Url.Action("Index")" method="POST">
```